# call 2 functions in a function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

The problem is as follows below:

Write a function compose that takes two functions as argument, we call them `Fa` and `Fb`, and returns a function, `Fres`, that means that outdata from the other function is indata to the first, ex: `Fres(x) = Fa(Fb(x))`.
run example:

```
>>> def multiply_five(n):
... return n * 5
...
>>> def add_ten(x):
... return x + 10
...
>>> composition = compose(multiply_five, add_ten)
>>> composition(3)
65
>>> another_composition = compose(add_ten, multiply_five)
>>> another_composition(3)
25
```

So as I understand this if I send in 3 the function compose will take 3+10 = 13
after that send that result into the multiply function it will do: 13*5 witch is 65.
this is the code I've written so far:

```
def multiply_five(n):
    return n*5

def add_ten(x):
    return x+10

def compose(func1, func2):
    def comp(arg):
        return func2(arg)
    return func1(comp(arg))
```

I get compile error, and I've tried some different approaches:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    composition = compose(multiply_five, add_ten)
  File "C:\Users\Jim\Desktop\tdp002\5h.py", line 10, in compose
    return func1(comp(arg))
NameError: name 'arg' is not defined
```

Comment: `arg` has not, as the error states, been defined at that point. What is it supposed to be? `func1`? `func2`? Some data structure or other object containing both?

Comment: hmm still gets the : args is not defined

Comment: why not just `def compose(func1, func2, n): return func1(func2(n))`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Because `compose` only takes the two functions as its arguments and it has to return the composed function.

Comment: @PM2Ring Oh, i see. I missread the question.

Comment: when you do this line: composition = compose(multiply_five, add_ten)
>>> composition(3) it should use 3 as argument to the both functions

Comment: @Jim No, it shouldn't, unless you aren't actually defining function composition.

Answer (score 7):

You don't want to call either `func1` or `func2` yet; you just want to return a function that *will* call them both.

```
def compose(func1, func2):
    def _(*args, **kw):
        return func1(func2(*args, **kw))
    return _
```

You could also just use a `lambda` expression to create the composed function.

```
def compose(func1, func2):
    return lambda *args, **kw: func1(func2(*args, **kw))
```

Comment: i get *kw as invalid syntax, what does kw stands for?

Comment: `kw` is just an arbitrary name; I have a typo and forgot the second `*`.

Comment: the lambda funktion works better, it does as the assignment says but i still dont understand what is **kw?

Comment: ok i see thank you very much appreciate it!

Comment: Yeah, this just generalizes to any possible function `func2` in terms of what arguments it expects. The only constraint is that `func1` must take a single argument, namely whatever `func2` returns. Generalizing composition to allows `func1` to be supplied multiple arguments and/or keyword arguments is one reason (IMO) that Python does not have function composition built-in.

Comment: @chepner There's `functools.partial` though.

Comment: That solves a different problem.

Comment: Let's say `func1` takes 2 arguments, and `func2` returns a tuple `(x, y)`. Should `compose(func1, func2) == lamda *args: func1(*func2(*args))`, or should it return something like `partial(func1, func2(*args))`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def compose(func1, func2):
    def comp(arg):
        return func1(func2(arg))
    return comp
```