# Call a function inside another function call

Tags: python, function, syntax

```
def func1(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4)
    ...

def func2(arg5,arg6)
    return a,b,c,d

func1(func2(arg5,arg6))
```

Can I call func1(func2(arg5,arg6)) like this??
as func2 will return 4 items that'll be passed to func1

Comment: @PavneetSingh That is certainly not a duplicate of this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40220660/call-2-functions-in-a-function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would have to unpack the arguments, but yes you can do that using [the `*` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters).

```
func1(*func2(arg5,arg6))
```

Comment: i upvoted your answer though the same question asked yesterday and got marked as duplicate , both links are provided but still nice answer +1